# Rails route not using name specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Here is a section of my routes file:

```
namespace :admin do
        namespace :gallery do
            post 'delete_collections',                           to: 'gallery#delete_collections'
            post 'import_collections',                           to: 'gallery#import_collections'

            post 'delete_albums',                                to: 'gallery#delete_albums'
            post 'import_albums',                                to: 'gallery#import_albums'
            post 'check_albums_photos',                          to: 'gallery#check_albums_photos'
            post 'check_album_photos/:id',                       to: 'gallery#check_album_photos'
            post 'reorder_albums',                               to: 'gallery#reorder_albums'

            post 'assign_albums_to_collections',                 to: 'gallery#assign_albums_to_collections'
            post 'reposition_collections',                       to: 'gallery#reposition_collections'

            post 'delete_gallery_items',                         to: 'gallery#delete_gallery_items'
            post 'rebuild_gallery_items',                        to: 'gallery#rebuild_gallery_items'
            post 'import_album/:flickr_album_id',                to: 'gallery#import_album', as: 'import_album'
            post 'import_album_complete/:flickr_album_id',       to: 'gallery#import_album_complete', as: 'import_album_complete'
            post 'delete_album/:flickr_album_id',                to: 'gallery#delete_album', as: 'delete_album'

            root  to: 'gallery#index'
end
end
```

For some reason, when I run `rails routes`, the output I get for the route "check_album_photos/:id" is `admin_gallery POST   /admin/gallery/check_album_photos/:id(.:format)                                                   admin/gallery/gallery#check_album_photos`

Any idea why this is?

It works if I add `as: "check_album_photos"` to the end of the route, but this seems wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the path from the given name space will be /admin/gallery and the name of the controller is gallery_controller I guess, that's why /admin/gallery + /gallery. If you want /admin/gallery, add it under admin namespace

Comment: @HarshSingh No, I want a route called admin_gallery_check_album_photos that accepts a single id as a parameter.    Why does it work when I use the "as:" option but not without?

Comment: It is just how routes are defined in Rails, the endpoint will be the controllers name, so if you want admin_gallery_check_album_photos you will have to make a controller named that. It's best practice to use Nouns as controller's name. It works with :as cuz it creates an alias of that name. https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/#h-use-nouns-instead-of-verbs-in-endpoint-paths